# IE11 textarea content issues

Tags: html, textarea, internet-explorer-11

We have a `textarea` in a popup dialog in our web app which has no content by default `<textarea></textarea>`, which works fine in IE <= 10, however on IE 11 it appears the the HTML following the `</textarea>` is included in the content of the textarea. We adding a single "space" to the content this problem goes away.

Is there a nicer fix to this than having to handle a single space in the content?